# Cobounded ⇒ cocompact?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, group-actions, packing-and-covering

> Assume $\Gamma$ acts by isometries on a separable Hilbert space $H$, and 
>   $$\operatorname{diam} H/\Gamma\le 1.$$ 
>   Is it true that $H/\Gamma$ is compact?

---

**Stupid example.** Assume the action of $\Gamma$ on $H=\ell_2$ is generated by coordinate translations $x_n\mapsto x_n+\epsilon_n$. Then 
$$\operatorname{diam} H/\Gamma=\tfrac12\cdot\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\epsilon_n^2}.$$ 
Thus, if $\operatorname{diam} H/\Gamma\le 1$ then $H/\Gamma$ is a quotient of Hilbert cube, and has to be compact.

Comment: Just a thought: Let $H=\ell_2$. Let $\Gamma$ be the subgroup of the additive group of $H$ generated by sequences with integral norms. Then $\Gamma$ acts on $H$ by translations. What is the diameter of $H/\Gamma$ and is the quotient compact? I do not have time to check it myself now. But it should not be that difficult. 

Comment: @Anton: Of course you did not say what $\Gamma$ is.

Comment: @Mark: (1) $diam=\infty$ (2) Γ is a group, what else can act?

Comment: @Anton: Since you have computed the diameter of the quotient, could you then give an example of two orbits arbitrary far apart? I thought of the following argument. Suppose that $f\in \ell_2$ has norm $M$. Subtract $[M]/M \cdot f$ (with integral norm $[M]$), get norm $<1$. Hence the diam. is at most 2. If I do not see something here,  did you consider already all subgroups  $\Gamma$ of  the additive group of $H$ acting by translations? 

Comment: @Mark: If the dimension of $H$ is at least 2, the group $\Gamma$ generated by vectors of integral norms is transitive: Given $f \in H, f\neq 0$, connect $v:=\frac{f}{||f||}$ to $-v$ via an arc $\phi\colon [0,1]\to H$ on the unit sphere and consider $w_t:=\phi(t)+f$. By the intermediate value theorem, $||w_{t_0}||$ will be integral for some $t_0$, so $f$ is the difference of two vectors of integral norm.

Comment: @Guntam: Then the diameter should be 0? 

Comment: @Anton: You should somehow reconcile your formula for the diameter with Guntam's fact. 

Comment: @Mark: There are a lot of misunderstanding above, but my example is correct.

Comment: @Anton: So you claim that Guntram's argument is wrong? Or you claim that there exists a transitive action with unbounded quotient? 

Comment: @Mark: how could possibly a transitive action (whose corresponding quotient has exactly one point!) be unbounded? In any case, the group $\Gamma$ in Anton's example is not the same as the one you used in your first comment.

Comment: @Mark: In the above comments people talk about different things and it creates a lot of misunderstandings. Simply start from scratch.

Comment: @Anton: Am I right and if $\Gamma$ is a subgroup of the additive group of $H$ acting by translation, then the answer to your question is "yes", because the quotient will always be a quotient of the Hilbert cube (provided it is bounded)?

Comment: @Mark: No. Γ is a subgroup of isometries. But even if it is then I do not see a clear proof...

Comment: @Anton: Translations *are* isometries (but not all isometries are translations). I was asking about a particular case of your question when $\Gamma\lt (H,+)$, that is $\Gamma$ is a subgroup of the additive group of $H$. I think this case should not be too difficult. 

Comment: @Mark: I agree --- if true it should not be difficult... 

Comment: @Anton: In your Comment, what is $q$? 

Comment: @Mark: any positive integer

Comment: @Anton: Is it possible that $L$ is finite dimensional, and $H$ is not while $diam(H/L)<1000$?  I assumed that dim$(H)=\infty$. Or this $H$ and the $H$ above are different? Perhaps you meant $R^q/L$?

Comment: @Mark: Yes, sure.

Comment: @Anton: MO does not send me replies to my comments, so perhaps it would be better if you copy them by email. The question about $R^d$ and $L$ is very nice. You may want to post a separate "follow up" question then. Also did you ask John Roe or Nigel Higson? I have a feeling that the original question should be known to specialists in functional analysis.  Also Sergei Ivanov (who should be in Pennstate now) may know the answer. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is "NO". To show this let us use the following:

> **Lemma.** Let $L$ be a lattice in $\mathbb R^q$ ($q$ is any positive integer). 
>   Assume $$\operatorname{diam} \mathbb R^q/L>1000.$$ 
>   Then there is a midpoint $m$ of two points in $L$ such that $|m-x|>1$ for any $x\in L$.

Modulo Lemma one can construct an action of parallel translations the following way:
Let us construct inductively a sequence of lattices $L_q$ on $\mathbb R^q$ such that $\mathop{diam} \mathbb R^q/L_q<1000$ and such that $|x|>1$ for any $x\in L$.
Start with standard $L_1=\mathbb Z$ in $\mathbb R$.
To construct $L_{q}$ take 
$$L_{q}'=L_{q-1}\times \mathbb Z\subset \mathbb R^{q-1}\times\mathbb R = \mathbb R^{q}.$$
If $\mathop{diam} \mathbb R^q/L'_q < 1000$ set $L_q = L'_q$.
Othewise pass to the minimal lattice which contains $L'_q$ and the midpoint provided by the Lemma.
Applying this construction finitely many times you get a lattice $L_q$ with $\mathop{diam} \mathbb R^q/L_q<1000$.

Continue the process, we get lattice $L_\infty$ in $H$ which is a $1000$-net, its fundamental doamin contains a ball of radius 1; i.e. $H/L_\infty$ is not compact.

*Proof of Lemma.*
For $z\in\mathbb R^q$, denote by $\rho(z)$ the minimal distance to a point in $L$.
Take a point $z\in\mathbb R^q$ which maximize distance to $L$.
So $\rho(z)\ge 1000$. Then there is a couple of points $x,y\in L$ such that
$\angle xzy\ge\pi/2$ and $|x-z|=|x-z|=\rho(z)$.
Let $m$ be the midpoint for $x$ and $y$.
Then 
$$|z-m|\le \frac{\rho(z)}{\sqrt{2}}$$ and therefore the distance from $m$ to any point of $L$ is at least $1000{\cdot}(1-\tfrac1{\sqrt{2}})>1$.     $\square$